# create view organised by year and month from one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have in SQL-Server a table like this

| A | CreatedAt |
| --- | --- |
| x | 2020-06-05 12:23:33.920 |
| x | 2021-09-15 12:23:33.920 |
| x | 2021-09-25 12:23:33.920 |

I need to create a view that gets the following data:

| Year | Jan | Feb | March | April | May | June | July | Aug | Sept | Oct | Nov | Dec | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2021 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

I know how to count by month but I struggle to then split the counting into two different rows, one for each year. Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to `GROUP BY` the `YEAR` part of the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Group by year(CreatedAt)` does the trick, with a case expression inside a `sum` or `count` for each month and the total:

```
select 
year(CreatedAt) as Year,
sum(case when month(CreatedAt) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Jan,
sum(case when month(CreatedAt) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Feb,
sum(case when month(CreatedAt) = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as March,
sum(case when month(CreatedAt) = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as April,
sum(case when month(CreatedAt) = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as May,
sum(case when month(CreatedAt) = 6 then 1 else 0 end) as June,
sum(case when month(CreatedAt) = 7 then 1 else 0 end) as July,
sum(case when month(CreatedAt) = 8 then 1 else 0 end) as Aug,
sum(case when month(CreatedAt) = 9 then 1 else 0 end) as Sept,
sum(case when month(CreatedAt) = 10 then 1 else 0 end) as Oct,
sum(case when month(CreatedAt) = 11 then 1 else 0 end) as Nov,
sum(case when month(CreatedAt) = 12 then 1 else 0 end) as Dec,
count(*) as Total
from table_name
group by year(CreatedAt);
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c8d7d4b9d18d82327f8b34ade7b21542)

Comment: Thanks, I am impressed with the quick solution. I had spent the whole afternoon doing substrings to get the month and other minor operations. Really useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15). Though personally I find [Zakaria's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71238210/8895292) more compact for this specific case.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8294ba56444ec3ced66bedfc1600da15)

```
SELECT 
      YearNum
      , [Jan]
      , [Feb]
      , [Mar]
      , [Apr]
      , [May]
      , [Jun]
      , [Jul]
      , [Aug]
      , [Sep]
      , [Oct]
      , [Nov]
      , [Dec]
      , ( [Jan] + [Feb] +[Mar]
           + [Apr] + [May] + [Jun]
           + [Jul] + [Aug] + [Sep]
           + [Oct] + [Nov] + [Dec]
        ) AS Total
FROM 
(
    SELECT ColumnA
          , DatePart(yyyy, CreatedAt) AS YearNum
          , Left(DateName(mm, CreatedAt), 3) AS MonthName
    FROM   YourTable
) t 
PIVOT (
   COUNT(ColumnA)
   FOR MonthName IN (
      [Jan]
      , [Feb]
      , [Mar]
      , [Apr]
      , [May]
      , [Jun]
      , [Jul]
      , [Aug]
      , [Sep]
      , [Oct]
      , [Nov]
      , [Dec]
   )
) AS pvt
```

Comment: Thanks I think this is also a valid solution. I have never used a pivot but it helps me to learn about it.

Comment: Yeah, I figure it's good to know there are multiple options, even if you don't use them right now. Glad it helped.

Comment: FORMAT is an expensive function to call - be careful when using it.

Comment: @SMor - I didn't know that. Thanks for the tip. After a brief search on format() and efficiency, I should've stuck with my first choice: dateName() and left(), haha